# Exponential map of flow, does it locally look like a power series/matrix exponential?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

Let $g_t : M \rightarrow M$ be the flow of a vector field, that is a family of diffeomorphisms such that $g_t \circ g_s = g_{t+s}$ to $t,s > 0$ and $g_0 = \operatorname{id}$.

One can interpret the diffeomorphism group as an infinite dimensional Lie group, up to some technicalities I am not interested in, with its Lie algebra given by vector fields. This group admits an exponential map that sometimes coincides with the Riemannian exponential map, namely there is an $\exp: \mathfrak{X}(M) \rightarrow Diff(M)$ such that:

$$\exp(tX) = g_t$$

Where $X : M \rightarrow TM$ is a vector field satisfying

$$\frac{d}{dt}g_t(x) = X(g_t(x))$$

My question is, using a coordinate chart a diffeomorphism can be represented locally as just a collection of mappings $g = (g_t^i)_{i=1}^n$ with $g^i_t = F^i(x,t) : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Similarly, a vector field can be identified as a first order differential operator that has components with respect to a basis induced by the same chart.

Can we say, that in a small neighbourhood we have:

$$\exp(tX) = \sum \frac{1}{k!}X^k$$

Where the RHS is some sort of operator/matrix exponential instead of some abstract time 1 geodesic map?

Comment: Basically yes. Formally you want to consider the action of $\exp(tX)$ on smooth functions.

Comment: If $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ how is $g(f)$ supposed to be interpreted? Pullback?

Comment: Yes, pullback. You don't need to work in local coordinates either.

Comment: I assume that knowledge of $g(f)$ for all $f$ is sufficient to recover the diffeomorphism $g$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.